# How can i pinpoint a circular object reference in a large collection of objects?

Tags: java, circular-reference

I am retrieving, and copying a quite large collection of folder objects from an external source. They all have a folder id, and a parent folder id, but does not come as a tree structure. after retrieving them, I organize them in tree node objects, with a top root. However, one or more of the folders creates a circular reference, and I am having trouble figuring out how to pinpoint where.

Java does not throw any errors when creating the circular reference. The error comes as a stackoverflow error, when I try to encode it to json format, before sending it to the client side of a web application. Because the error is first visible to me then, I can't see which object is the cause of the error at all.

In this particular problem, I am at a loss of a strategy. Are there any standardized, or good ways of recognizing circular object references, like the one in my case?

Comment: Can a folder have more than one parent? You talk about folder objects. Is it a collection of child-parent relationships or folder objects that have exactly one parent?

Comment: Exactly one parent. I found out that the error was in my own refining code, and not in the objects references.

Comment: I was wondering. If each node has exactly one parent I wasn't sure how you were building the object tree. It's hard to do unless you find all the root nodes, then keep adding nodes with parents already instantiated and so on. If there are loops you'll get to the end with nodes that have no parent in the tree. That's because they form loops. Loops almost pop out the end of the algorithm.

Comment: I know from the start which folder id i want as the root. Then I simply make a hashmap, with folder id as key, and place all folder objects there, but at the same time, I wrap them in node objects, which has possibility to define subfolders. afterwards I go through all of the raw folder objects, and find both id and parent id, before using those two on the map, to add each folder to it's parent folder. I did however have a mistake in my code, so I ended up setting a foldernode as a subfolder of itself.

Comment: Lastly, I simply retrieve the one I know is the root, and send it, and its now defined tree structure, to the client side, in json format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a "visited" boolean flag to the node class, initialized to false.  Traverse the tree. If at a given node the flag is true when you arrive then you have detected a loop. Otherwise set the flag to true and continue traversing the tree.  Makes no differernce which traversal order you use (pre= post- or in-order).